# Get port signal mapping Excel file from PDF schematic

Tags: schematics, tools, remappable-pins

I would like to know on an open source tool which exists to get port signal mapping Excel file from PDF schematic. It will be super useful to me, as the current design has a high pin count FPGA, and 500+ components on the PCB.

It will be useful if a tool could do this from a PDF version of the schematic, but just any other ASCII schematic format is fine as well.

I am looking for this shortcut as I am a FPGA programmer, and do not want to do the hardware engineer's job of mapping the signals of the entire PCB design.

Comment: I’m not following what you want. If you want pin mapping data, that is usually extracted from the netlist. Once it has got as far a a pdf, its probably too late. Pdf is not really a good format for extracting the data. Besides, don’t the fpga guys dictate the pinouts? If you leave it for the pcb guys to decide, then you might have PnR issues.

Comment: PDF files are just lines, curves, shapes and text. There won't be any schema in it.

Comment: Yes then it is too late. The design is a legacy design and the netlist does not exist for it. I guess I have to manually map the lines from the alt tabing with the pdf file. I was going to dictate th pinouts in the new design, but wanted a faster way of doing pin mapping for the previous pdf schematic that I had.